# Time relay with external impulse trigger

Tags: relay

I have garage door opener which I want to use to control external light during closing or opening.
This is how my output looks like at door motor:

[image: Door opener outputs]

In order to achieve light control I have remote switch in my light and remote relay connected to motor. Now the question is when to detect if door is opening or closing. For this purpose I can use **Flash** output( as a trigger signal) which is supposed to be used by blinking alarm light. But the thing is I don't want my external light to blink but to being turned on constantly.

To solve this problem I've decided to use [this](https://zamel.com/en-GB/products/exta-building-automation/time-relays/pcp-0424v) time relay which will convert blinking signal to constant one.
According to this picture as a trigger signal I can connect anything +/-, L/N

[image: time relay]

So I set proper mode which is:
[image]

And connected everything as follows:
[image]

But it doesn't work. I was playing with this relay a bit and it turned out that it is not triggering when I connect **red** line to **+24V** but it does when I connect it to the **GND**

What am I doing wrong?

Why rising or trailing edge is working with ground and not positive?

**UPDATE**

[Manual in english](https://zamel.com/en/exta/pcp-04-instrukcja.pdf) for similar relay - 230V AC only instead of 24V AC/DC

This is connection diagram from manual:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that probably the input is looking for a connection toward ground (a current sink), while the flash output is only capable of *sourcing* current.

In normal usage how is the flash lamp connected? Flash and GND or Flash and +24?

Also, I have not found a cabling manual for your relay so I cannot really say. It could be simply designed to work that way.

Comment: Flash should be connected to GND. I've attached link to manual and diagram.